# Is this 'X was when' expression idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, free-relative-clauses

> This award (was given to me) was when I was in the fourth grade.
>
> This movie (was released) was when X was the most popular guy in the industry.

Are these two expressions without the parenthesized phrase idiomatic? If yes, is there any difference between the one with and the one without parenthesized text?

Comment: I have no problem with the second sentence in either form, but the first sentence sounds "off" without the parenthetical statement. I'd word it as: _This award **is from** when I was in the fourth grade._

Comment: @J.R. "This movie was when..." definitely sounds off to me, personally. The movie was *what*, when [x]? I feel like both sentences need the parenthetical element and to remove the second *was*; that is, "This award was given to me when..." and "This movie was released when..." Thoughts?

Comment: @Wendi: Yes, or "This movie was from when…" where "from" is short for "from the era when…" I think I misread the original when I made my opening remark.

Comment: @WendiKidd But you can say "the tragedy was when […]." Indeed, replacing _tragedy_ with _movie_ doesn't make the sentence sound correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these is idiomatic, either with or without the text in parentheses.

*When [CLAUSE]* is an expression of time. It has two uses:

1. As an **adverbial** it modifies a verb or clause, and there has to be a verb or clause for it to modify:

   > [Main clause]         [*when CLAUSE*].
   >   [This award **was given** to me] [*when I was in the fourth grade*].
   >   [This movie **was released**]   [*when X was the most popular guy in the industry*].

   Note that there is no *was* linking the two clauses. The *WHEN-clause* is a subordinate adjunct which modifies the sentence.
2. As a **free relative clause** it acts as a [Noun Phrase]. It may be used as a predicate complement with *BE*, but the subject has to be something which can be a time expression: a **date**, or a (dateable) **occasion**.

   > [Occasion]              **was** [*when CLAUSE*].
   >   [The highlight of my academic career] **was** [*when I was in the fourth grade*].
   >   [1992]                **was** [*when X was the most popular guy in the industry*].

   The *WHEN-clause* is a constituent of the sentence.